# Nav Tag Display Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this nav tag in my website
I want to divide it into two when the device width reached to the specified px in CSS3 media queries.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .nav-links>a {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-links">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
</nav>
```

How can I make it so it will look like 2 lines of navigation link in the frontend. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav-links {
  margin: 10px;
}
.nav-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-links a {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-links">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Yea mate.. if you got problem please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for? From your question this is what i understood.

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-links">
  <div>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <a href="#">Other</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```